# is this looking stupid? inserting 2 form fields into mysql database safely

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

hey so I have 2 input fields trying to get them to go into a database nicely been looking around trying to puzzle the thing together can someone nudge me in the right direction? :)

```
  <?php
    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$subsc_hostname", "$subsc_username", "$subsc_password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$subsc_database")or die("cannot select DB");

    // name and email from form fields 
    $subsc_name=$_POST['sub_name']; 
    $subsc_email=$_POST['sub_email']; 


    // Atttempt to protect against MySQL injection 
    $subsc_name = stripslashes($subsc_name);
    $subsc_email = stripslashes($subsc_email);
    $subsc_name = mysql_real_escape_string($subsc_name);
    $subsc_email = mysql_real_escape_string($subsc_email);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE subsc_name='$subsc_name' and subsc_email='$subsc_email'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched table row must be 1
    if($count==0){
    $sql="INSERT INTO subscribers(subsc_name, subsc_email)VALUES('$subsc_name', '$subsc_email')";   
    }
    else {
    echo "Already Subscribed";
    }

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_name" />
        <br>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_email" />

            <div class="pull-right">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
            </div>

        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: You don't appear to actually be executing the `INSERT` query...

Comment: You really, really, REALLY should be using prepared statements: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: don't check with SELECT. make the name+email pair unique in the database, and *try* to INSERT.

Comment: `if($count<1){` should do the trick. But as others have stated, you should really buckle down and use PDO instead because `mysql_query()` and all other `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Just look at the big red warning http://us3.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: not really. the user could send two requests simultaneously, both seeing count=0.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements if you want to protect against sql injection. Also, don't use mysql, use mysqli or PDO.

For mysqli, see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

For PDO, see: https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements